# Is there a different command for php 5.4?

Tags: php, webserver

I have a webserver (on bluehost) that says to run php 5.4 but when I try to run

```
php --version
```

then I get `5.2.17` printed. Is there some special parameter or different command to get version 5.4? OR can you please offer some workaround?

(I mean with C++11 you have to type g++ -std=c++11.)

Comment: There could be multiple installed PHP versions. E.g `/usr/local/bin/php52` and `/usr/local/bin/php5.4` (Possibly with /usr/local/bin/php being a softlink to the 5.2 version).  What does `locate php`, or `find / -iname "php*" -ls` show you ?

Comment: @Hennes: thx! `find / -name "php*" -ls` was the solution, `/bin/php54s` was the program to run.